# how to edit akka application.conf

Tags: scala, configuration, akka

I am searching for days for a tutorial on how to write a custom application.conf. I read the akka-documentation and tried the Pi example.

But now I want to run my own configuration. My goal is to override the router type and change the number of routees. Here is my code:

```
package org.sddb.playground

import akka.actor._
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import akka.routing.RoundRobinRouter

object Test extends App {

  case object Log
  case object Ask

  class Tester extends Actor with ActorLogging {

    def receive = {
      case Log => logging
      case Ask => answer
    }

    def logging {
      log error "error"
      log warning "warning"
      log debug "debug"
    }

    def answer {
      log info "somebody asked"
    }
  }
  val config = ConfigFactory.load
  val system = ActorSystem("TestSystem", config.getConfig("test"))
  val tester = system.actorOf(Props[Tester].withRouter(RoundRobinRouter(2)))
  tester ! Log
  tester ! Ask
  tester ! PoisonPill
  system.shutdown
}
```

My application.config looks that way:

```
test {
  akka.loglevel = DEBUG
  deployment {
    /tester {
      router = broadcast
      nr-of-instances = 5
    }
  }
}
```

The loging on debug level is ok but there is neither a broadcast nor are there 5 instances.
Where is my misstake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because you are creating a RoundRobinRouter(2) explicitly. You have to pass `FromConfig()` instead and also you have to pass "tester" as name.

edit:

Your config section is wrong, it should be:

```
test {
  akka.loglevel = DEBUG
  akka.actor.deployment {
    /tester {
      router = broadcast
      nr-of-instances = 5
    }
  }
}
```

But you could also just do

```
akka {
  loglevel = DEBUG
  actor {
    deployment {
      /tester {
        router = broadcast
        nr-of-instances = 5
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then you don't have to pass in the config manually.

Comment: Where exactly do I have to pass "tester"?

Comment: The second parameter of `system.actorOf` is the name of the actor.

Comment: I changed the line to: val tester = system.actorOf(Props[Tester].withRouter(FromConfig()), name = "tester")
but now I get an ConfigurationException.

Comment: What does the exception say? Btw. you don't have to create an own section in the config, just use akka{} instead of test{} and don't pass in the config on the creation of your system.

Oh and it's `akka.actor.deployment`, not `akka.deployment`. Maybe that is the error.

Comment: The Exception says Actor[akka://TestSystem/user/tester] needs external configurationfrom file

Comment: Please try the suggestion from my last comment.